# using Geocoder to return a list of all street names of a selected city in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

if i have a city retrieved by:

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
Address address = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

Is there any way to get list of all street names in a selected town using the google maps api?

**UPDATE**

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses.size() > 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                Log.e("afaf", " " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i));
```

this returns (for example): new york, 5th street 3924.And it doesn't iterate on all city streets.

Comment: loop also the address array list

Comment: this is not allowed: `addresses.getMaxAddressLineIndex()`

Comment: yes it is not possible because addresses is a `List<Address>` look at my update.

Comment: this doens't work, it returns only the street name of the city where is my location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your looking for is this:

[getFromLocationName (String locationName, int maxResults)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

From the docs :

> Returns an array of Addresses that are known to describe the named
>   location, which may be a place name such as "Dalvik, Iceland", an
>   address such as "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA", an
>   airport code such as "SFO", etc.. The returned addresses will be
>   localized for the locale provided to this class's constructor.
>
> The query will block and returned values will be obtained by means of
>   a network lookup. The results are a best guess and are not guaranteed
>   to be meaningful or correct. It may be useful to call this method from
>   a thread separate from your primary UI thread.

to get the Street name use this(I think you already know this):

```
  for(int a = 0 ; a < addresses.size() ; a++){
    Address address = addresses.get(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
       // get address like address.getAddressLine(i); 
    }
  }
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for the asnwer, can you provide me an example on retrieve all street names of a city, using that you suggested.because i tried this, but with this returns only the name of the street of the given location.

Comment: have u tried putting the city name or the the town as first parameter?

Comment: please note that `getFromLocationName` is currently broken if you try to specify geo bounds - please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75575

Comment: i tried but as before,this doens't work, it returns only the street name of the city where is my location.

Comment: yes seems like theres a really big issue with geocoder.

Comment: well you can still use the http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat_example+","+lang_example+"&sensor=true which you can really count on. but the question at first was android-api like i really thought that of built-in android api. sorry

Comment: so, in conclusion with android api, is not possible to achieve this?

Comment: well it works for me. the issue @PavelDudka referring to was getFromLocationName that has a bounding location.

Comment: can you provide me a full example of your solution(you said taht worked). I have defined location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62466/discussion-between-spurdow-and-cimat).